# how to pass $_product instance to createBlock in Magento?

Tags: product, configurable-product, blocks, template, magento-1

I want to pass `$_product` instance to `createBlock`, I have done below code but it does not working. I have written this code on product listing page `list.phtml` file.

```
echo Mage::app()->getLayout()
 ->createBlock('easylife_switcher/catalog_product_view_type_configurable_config')
 ->setTemplate('easylife_switcher/catalog/product/view/type/configurable/config.phtml')
 ->setProduct($_product)->toHtml();
```

Below is `config.phtml` file code.

```
<?php if (Mage::helper('easylife_switcher')->isEnabled()) : ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var switcherConfig = <?php echo $this->getJsonAdditionalConfig() ?>;
    document.observe('dom:loaded', function(){
        if (spConfig){
            spConfig = new Easylife.Switcher(Object.extend(spConfig.config, switcherConfig));
        }
    });
//]]>
</script>
```

Below is the `getJsonAdditionalConfig()` function code:

```
public function getJsonAdditionalConfig()
{
    var_dump($this->getProduct()->getId());exit;
}
```

Right now it returns

```
Call to a member function getId() on null in
```

How can I pass $_product instance to `easylife_switcher` block.

Thanks

Comment: try to echo the Product Id before `echo Mage::app() [...]`. If you get the same error, you know your `$_product` Variable  hasn't a valid Product Model. If you get the ID try to figure out what class `$_product` is. You can test it with something like `echo get_class($this->getProduct());` in the `getJsonAdditionalConfig()` method.

Comment: I print the product id before `Mage::app()[...]` using `echo $_product->getId()` it's working return product id. and also i print the class using `echo get_class($this->getProduct());` the output is `Easylife_Switcher_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Configurable_Config` it's return class name

Comment: do you tried to echo the class inside the `getJsonAdditionalConfig()` method? Try this inside of `getJsonAdditionalConfig()`: var_dump($this->getProduct()->debug());` Do you see any Product data? Your next step could be to pass other data to your Template like: `->setFoo('bar')->toHtml();` and see if you can echo it. I think the best way to debug it with xdebug.

Comment: Yes i print class name inside the `getJsonAdditionalConfig()` function. and i tried `debug()` it's return `Call to a member function debug() on null`

Answer (score 0):

After some time I've found a possible solution, try to add

```
Mage::register('product', $product)
Mage::register('current_product', $product) // used for "qtyInstallments"
```

**Before** the

`echo Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock()[..]` and

**remove**

`->setProduct($product)` from it (I've tried this `setProduct()` too, without success).

This will put `$product` on "**registry**", like

> app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php

`getProduct()` method (around line 89) is expecting :D

Answer (score 0):

Not Right: `$block->setProduct($_product);`

Right: `$block->setData('product', $_product);`

Or: `$block->addData(['product'=>$_product]);`

And Get: `$this->getData('product');`

Also you can try: pass only product_id

```
$block->setData('product_id', $_product->getId());
```

And after:

```
private function getProduct(){
    $model = Mage::getModel();
    if($this->getData('product_id')){
        $model->load($this->getData('product_id'));
    }
    return $model->getId();
}
```

Or Combine Methods:

```
class ... {
    private $product;
    public function setProduct(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $_product){
        $this->product = $_product;
        return $this;
    }
    private function getProduct(){
        if(!$this->product){
             if($this->getData('product')){
                 $this->product = $this->getData('product');
             }
        }
        if(!$this->product){
             $model = Mage::getModel();
             if($this->getData('product_id')){
                 $model->load($this->getData('product_id'));
             }
             $this->product = $model;
        }
        return $this->product;
    }
}
```